React-Native Expo API Call Not Working in Android
I am using react native expo to develop an app that can upload images to an external API. When I run it on web it works, but when I use an android phone or an iphone, the API call doesn't work and I get the following log error:
LOG  {"error": "invalid_client", "error_description": "Bad client credentials"}
Here is my code:
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import {View, Button, Image, Pressable} from 'react-native';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function Imageupload(){
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    const [content, setContent] = useState(null);
    const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
    const [invoice, setInvoice] = useState('');

    useEffect(() =>{
      fetch('https://url1', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br'
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams({
          'client_id' : 'mobile_android',
          'client_secret' : 'secret',
          'grant_type' : 'client_credentials'
        })
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setContent(data.access_token);
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
    }, []);
    const pickImage = async () => {
    const picked = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
    setResult(picked);
    console.log(result);
    console.log(content);
    if (!result.canceled) {
      setImage(result.assets[0].uri);
    } 
  }
  const upload = () =>{
    let form = new FormData();
    form.append('invoiceImages', {
      uri : image,
      name: result.assets[0].fileName,
      type: result.assets[0].mimeType
    })
    fetch('https://url2', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers : {
        'Authorization' : `Bearer ${content}`,
        'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br'
      },
      body: form
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.ok){
        console.log("successful");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.message);
      console.log("Failure");
    });
  }
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput value = {invoice} onChangeText={setInvoice} placeholder='Enter Invoice Number'/>
      <View>
        <Pressable onPress={pickImage}><Text>Pick an Image</Text></Pressable>
      </View>
      <View>
        {image ? <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={styles.image}/> : null}
        <Pressable onPress = {upload}><Text>Upload Image</Text></Pressable>
      </View>
      <View><Text>{JSON.stringify(content)}</Text></View>                                           
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    alignItems : 'center',
  },
  image: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  }
})

I've used 'url1' and 'url2' to indicate the urls, I am not allowed to disclose them. Please let me know what's wrong with this.
I do have an auxiliary question as well - I get a CORS error when doing the second API call. Will this error stop when I switch from web to android/ios or will it persist there as well?
Should I try to use a proxy server instead to fix the issue?
